# How Do I Create An iCal (.ics) File Programmatically?

Tags: icalendar

Within a client-side JS application, I would like for users to be able to export an event on my site to their Apple iCalender. How do I construct that file so that they can download it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple iCalender can import .ics (RFC 5545) extension files. The best site I've seen documenting how to represent the necessary metadata within one of these files is here: https://icalendar.org/.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server) explains how to deal with creating the file and downloading it from within a JS client.

Note: You want to set a data content type of: 'text/calendar;charset=utf-8;'.